# How to export outlook 2007 emails on imap account?

Tags: outlook, imap, export

When i go to export it only allows to export from Archives or Personal folder.
Account i have in list is myname@mysite.com is not available for export why?

Comment: Hi sorry i lost password for my account i was not using Exchange at all its standard IMAP server. My PST points to separate file not archive

Answer (score 1):

I JUST did this for a company two weeks ago while moving them to hosted Exchange (you can't import to Exchange directly from an Outlook IMAP PST...you can, but things will black hole when you drop them into previously made IMAP folders since they look for a location no longer available), and I made mistakes that would have lost e-mail (of course, not permanently with IMAP) had I not done it again.

The first thing to do is to (in Office 2010, so find the similar location in previous versions) Send/Receive>Send Receive Groups>Define Send Receive Groups>Edit and check the box to "Download complete items including attachments. This will make sure that you have all the mail locally and that you don't just export headers. This is the real trick behind doing this since it is not the default.

You need to then create a new PST file. From there, there are two ways to work it.

1. Close the IMAP PST and then do an import into the new PST, which is not IMAP (when you import, it will re-open the IMAP PST temporarily while it copies the data). I used import rather than export, but should achieve what I believe you are asking for.
2. Keep both PSTs open, and just do a copy (not move, just in case).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, per default, the pst. points to archieve. 
How to manage .pst files, take a look in the KB here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287070/en-us

This should do it. If you have access to the exchangeserver, you can use the exmerge too, to export entire mailboxes. 
For reference, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174197